# C#: Create a Custom Control textbox which triggers events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, custom-controls

I'm making a custom control textbox that has a `Cue` *(filler text)* and `CueColor` *(filler text color)* properties. I created an `Enter` and `Leave` event inside the textbox to regulate the Cue. When I tried applying it, however, it crashes my IDE (Visual Studio 2015, if this helps).

I've read a few posts with similar questions:
[Winforms user controls custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188059/winforms-user-controls-custom-events)

Although I'm not quite sure if my problem has the same solution. How do I make it work? Here is my code for clarity:

```
class CueTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public string Cue
        {
            get { return Cue; }
            set { Cue = value;}
        }

        public Color CueColor
        {
            get { return CueColor; }
            set { CueColor = value; }
        }

        private void CueTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
            if (t.ForeColor == this.CueColor)
            {
                t.Text = "";
                t.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;
            }
        }

        private void CueTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
            if (t.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                t.Text = Cue;
                t.ForeColor = this.CueColor;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before compiling your project you have to make sure that you have added your custom control's DLL into library.

Comment: Where do I find a custom control's DLL?

Comment: check this i hope it would resolve your issue. Thanks http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ehtesham.dotnet/how-to-create-a-custom-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I see in your code is that the property definitions are recursively calling themselves and this will cause a stack overflow when adding the control to the design surface.

```
   public string Cue
    {
        get { return Cue; }
        set { Cue = value;}
    }
```

Either define a backing field or use auto-implemented properties.

```
    private string cue = String.Empty;
    public string Cue
        {
        get { return cue; }
        set { cue = value; }
        }
```

or

```
public string Cue { get; set; }
```

Your question implied adding event handlers caused the issue.  This can be a problem for custom controls at times.  There is the [Control.DesignMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property that is meant to allow conditional execution of code.  However, it does not operate in the constructor.  You need to do a bit of a hack to determine if the IDE is active.

This property can be used for development in Visual Studio as an alternative to `DesignMode`.

```
    private bool InDesignMode
        {
        get
            {
            return (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode == System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) || 
                    base.DesignMode || 
                    (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv");
            }
        }
```

In solution development of custom controls is an exercise in self abuse.  You are better of to go to Project Properties->Debug Tab and set the "Start Action" to "Start External Program" with "devenv.exe" as the program.  This will start a new instance of VS when you "run" the debugger.  When you add a control to the design surface of the new VS instance, you can debug your control's code.  Break points will be hit and exceptions displayed.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks! You just saved me from a headache. Never expected that to be the error. :)

Comment: @DonovanKeating,  I added some info that you may find useful for further developing custom controls.